# I need help fixing my leaking shower valve

Tags: repair, shower, leak, valve, antique

I have an old shower valve that is from the 1940's that has a slow leak. I would like to repair it, but I can't find any of the typical screws to take it apart. Even after taking the handle off there are now visible screws. Has anyone seen this style before?[image]

Comment: Have you checked from the back side? I have found a couple of old homes that the parts were bolted on the other side of the wall.